# How to update a Listview in fragment

Tags: listview, android-fragments

I usually don't post here unless it is a last resort but this is the hardest Android problem I've encountered.

I've got a main activity and two fragments. One fragment displays a listview created with a cursor adapter, and another fragment with an edit text that allows the user to add text to a sqlite database. The common problem I see in many posts is that an item can be added to the database via a data entry fragment, but when you switch to the listview fragment the new entry is not refreshed in the list. As many have posted the only way to view the new entry is quit the app and start it again, upon which the new database entries show up in the list. Alternatively, I added a button to the listview fragment that updates the listview.

Many have suggested creating an interface that offers communication between fragments through the main activity. However this approach throws the familiar java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method.

Now I have a page adapter that manages the fragments and it seems that once the pages have been created you cannot update the listview because calls to the database require a context which appears to be null.

The code for a simple example (without implementing an interface) can be found on Git at this url: [Repository](https://github.com/escape-radius/CursorListBAK.git)

I'm really at a loss. It seems saving to a database and updating a listview in another fragment shouldn't be that difficult, but it is indeed proving to be so.

Comment: paste your code here

Comment: thats the project, post the code which is not working for you, or where you have trouble

Comment: The code is a working example that can be used as a starting point. I have dozens of implementations that don't work, so I find it pointless to include code that provides no viable solution.